# Facebook Graph API: Making public post on user's page

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a Django web app that interacts with Facebook.

When a user does a certain action in my site, I want to make a public post on their wall. I use the API like so:

```
user.facebook_graph_api.put_object(
    'me', 'feed',
    message=my_message,
    link=my_link, 
    privacy=json.dumps(
        {'value': 'EVERYONE'}
    )
)
```

But for some reason, the post is made with privacy setting of "Friends", not "Public", despite the fact that I've set `{'value': 'EVERYONE'}`. **Why? How can I make it have a privacy setting of "Public"?**

(Initially I suspected it's because the test user I used, which is myself, as a global privacy level of "Friends", but I've tried again with the global privacy level changed to both "Public" and "Only me" and it had no effect on the privacy of the post made by the app.)

Comment: Did you check the settings for your app (Default Activity Privacy)? You can set the default for your app to everyone, but someone's individual privacy settings can override it when they authorize the app. I would try to delete the app, and reauthorize with the user set to public as you described in your question. Look closely at what permissions you are asking for when the app is authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what @therewillbesnacks said...

The default privacy level requested by you app is the ceiling for posts' privacy

> **Note**: The privacy parameter only applies for posts to the user's own timeline and is ultimately governed by the privacy ceiling a user has configured for an app.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

You need to edit your app's Default Activity Privacy, and Facebook has done a good job of hiding. Here's how to find it

1. Go to your list of apps (https://developers.facebook.com/apps?view=all_apps)
2. Click on your app
3. Click on 'App Details'
4. Scroll down to 'App Center Listed Platforms' and click on the button on the right that says 'Configure App Center Permissions'
5. Change the 'Default Activity Privacy' to public

Note that if a client changes that option, they have to remove and re-add your app to get it back to public. Which is what you'll have to do for your test account.

Comment: Has Facebook removed the 'Default Activity Privacy' section? I went to my app's 'Configure App Center Permissions' section, and 'Default Activity Privacy' is not there.